# Is there a python xml parser library that allows removing nodes without modifying the xml file layout (namespace/indentation)

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml code that looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<datamodel version="7.0" 
           xmlns="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/16/root.xsd" 
           xmlns:a="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/16/attribute.xsd" 
           xmlns:v="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/06/schema.xsd" 
           xmlns:d="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/06/data.xsd">

  <d:ctr type="AUTOSAR" factory="autosar" 
         xmlns:ad="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/08/admindata.xsd" 
         xmlns:cd="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/08/customdata.xsd" 
         xmlns:f="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/14/formulaexpr.xsd" 
         xmlns:icc="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/08/implconfigclass.xsd" 
         xmlns:mt="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/11/multitest.xsd"  
         xmlns:variant="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/11/variant.xsd">
    <d:lst type="TOP-LEVEL-PACKAGES">
      <d:ctr name="Lin" type="AR-PACKAGE">
        <d:lst type="ELEMENTS">
          <d:chc name="Lin" type="AR-ELEMENT" value="MODULE-CONFIGURATION">
            <d:ctr type="MODULE-CONFIGURATION">
              <a:a name="DEF" value="ASPath:/TS_T16D27M10I10R0/EcucDefs/Lin"/>
              <a:a name="IMPORTER_INFO" value="ImportEcuConfig"/>
              <d:var name="IMPLEMENTATION_CONFIG_VARIANT" type="ENUMERATION" 
                     value="VariantPostBuild">
                <a:a name="IMPORTER_INFO" value="@DEF"/>
              </d:var>
              <d:lst name="LinDemEventParameterRefs" type="MAP"/>
              <d:ctr name="LinGeneral" type="IDENTIFIABLE">
                <d:var name="LinDevErrorDetect" type="BOOLEAN" value="true"/>
                <d:var name="LinMultiCoreErrorDetect" type="BOOLEAN" 
                       value="true"/>
                <d:var name="LinIndex" type="INTEGER" value="0">
                  <a:a name="IMPORTER_INFO" value="@DEF"/>
                </d:var>
                <d:var name="LinTimeoutDuration" type="INTEGER" value="300">
                  <a:a name="IMPORTER_INFO" value="@DEF"/>
                </d:var>
              </d:ctr>
            </d:ctr>
          </d:chc>
        </d:lst>
      </d:ctr>
    </d:lst>
  </d:ctr>
</datamodel>
```

I would like to find an easy parser in python that allows me to parse this file and remove some nodes, without modifying any indentation, spaces char etc.. I have tried different solutions:

- xml.etree.ElementTree : messes up with the namespaces
- lxml.etree : fine with the namespaces, but it reorganises the attributes and line length and indentation
- simple sed script: does not deal well with elements that have children, that have explicit closing tag etc...

Ideally, I would just need a very simple stream parser that detects the start and end and just lets me remove the ones I do not want anymore.

Comment: Have you tried using lxml through BeautifulSoup?
https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?#parsing-xml

Comment: @Forcetti: I will try it, but I was expecting a smaller piece of code

Comment: Aside: Spaces, indentation, self-closing tags etc. do not qualitatively change the XML content. Unless for presentation purposes, why the need? Any library/tool that conforms to W3C rules should not require such formatting. And specs make no rule of attribute order. This does not include removing namespaces which does change XML content.

Answer (score 1):

Pfeww, that was not as easy as I expected it to be.  I ended up using `xml.parser.expat` to have access to the content of the string before the parsing, using the parser `.GetInputContext()`.

Then, catching the various events and implementing two states: forward and discard, I could copy the input string as they are in the original source file.

I have added some goodies to:

- support using short form of nodes when the content is entirely removed
- remove leading indentation of removed node

known issue:

- if there is ">" or "/>" in the content of the attributes of an element, this will fail (see todo in the below code)

```py
import io
import xml.parsers.expat

class xmlFilter:
    def __init__(self, fout, parser, encoding="iso-8859-1"):
        self.fout = fout
        self.parser = parser

        self._pending_start_element = False
        self._depth_count = 0
        self._pending_character_data = b""

        self.switch_out_discard()

    def switch_out_discard(self):
        self.parser.CommentHandler = self.comment
        self.parser.StartElementHandler = self.start_element
        self.parser.EndElementHandler = self.end_element
        self.parser.CharacterDataHandler = self.character_data

    def switch_in_discard(self):
        self.parser.CommentHandler = self.comment_discard
        self.parser.StartElementHandler = self.start_element_discard
        self.parser.EndElementHandler = self.end_element_discard
        self.parser.CharacterDataHandler = self.character_data_discard

    def handle_pending_start_at_start(self):
        if self._pending_start_element:
            self.fout.write(b">")
            self._pending_start_element = False
        self.fout.write(self._pending_character_data)
        self._pending_character_data = b""

    def comment_discard(self, data):
        pass

    def start_element_discard(self, name, attrs):
        self._depth_count += 1

    def end_element_discard(self, name):
        self._depth_count -= 1
        if self._depth_count == 0:
            self.switch_out_discard()

    def character_data_discard(self, data):
        pass

    def comment(self, data):
        self.handle_pending_start_at_start()
        self.fout.write(b"<!-- " + bytes(data, "UTF-8") + b"-->")

    def start_element(self, name, attrs):
        if "name" in attrs and attrs["name"] == "IMPORTER_INFO":
            self._depth_count = 1
            self.switch_in_discard()

            # we are explicitely not handling the pending start to be able to
            # create a short form node if there is no data

            # remove the trailing spaces to remove the indentation
            self._pending_character_data = self._pending_character_data.rstrip()
        else:
            self.handle_pending_start_at_start()

            ctx = self.parser.GetInputContext()
            # look for the next xml closing element
            # TODO: support the > and /> that are inside attributes
            brack1 = ctx.index(b">")
            # it is possible that there is no short close
            try:
                brack2 = ctx.index(b"/>")
            except ValueError:
                brack2 = 99999999
            if brack1 < brack2:
                data = ctx[:brack1]
            else:
                data = ctx[:brack2]
            self._pending_start_element = True
            self.fout.write(data)

    def end_element(self, name):
        if self._pending_start_element:
            if len(self._pending_character_data.rstrip()) == 0:
                self.fout.write(b"/>")
            else:
                self.fout.write(b">")
                self.fout.write(self._pending_character_data)
                self.fout.write(b"</" + bytes(name, "UTF-8") + b">")
            self._pending_start_element = False
        else:
            self.fout.write(self._pending_character_data)
            self.fout.write(b"</" + bytes(name, "UTF-8") + b">")
        self._pending_character_data = b""

    def character_data(self, data):
        self._pending_character_data += bytes(data, "UTF-8")


data = b'''
'''
fout = io.BytesIO()
fout.write(b"<?xml version='1.0'?>\n")
parser = xml.parsers.expat.ParserCreate()
filter = xmlFilter(fout, parser)
parser.Parse(data)
print(fout.getvalue().decode("utf-8"))
```

Input is:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<datamodel version="7.0" 
           xmlns="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/16/root.xsd" 
           xmlns:a="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/16/attribute.xsd" 
           xmlns:v="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/06/schema.xsd" 
           xmlns:d="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/06/data.xsd">

  <d:ctr type="AUTOSAR" factory="autosar" 
         xmlns:ad="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/08/admindata.xsd" 
         xmlns:cd="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/08/customdata.xsd" 
         xmlns:f="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/14/formulaexpr.xsd" 
         xmlns:icc="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/08/implconfigclass.xsd" 
         xmlns:mt="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/11/multitest.xsd"  
         xmlns:variant="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/11/variant.xsd">
    <d:lst type="TOP-LEVEL-PACKAGES">
      <d:ctr name="Lin" type="AR-PACKAGE">
        <d:lst type="ELEMENTS">
          <d:chc name="Lin" type="AR-ELEMENT" value="MODULE-CONFIGURATION">
            <d:ctr type="MODULE-CONFIGURATION">
              <a:a name="DEF" value="ASPath:/TS_T16D27M10I10R0/EcucDefs/Lin"/>
              <a:a name="IMPORTER_INFO" value="ImportEcuConfig"/>
              <d:var name="IMPLEMENTATION_CONFIG_VARIANT" type="ENUMERATION" 
                     value="VariantPostBuild">
                <a:a name="IMPORTER_INFO" value="@DEF"/>
              </d:var>
              <d:lst name="LinDemEventParameterRefs" type="MAP"/>
              <d:ctr name="LinGeneral" type="IDENTIFIABLE">
                <d:var name="LinDevErrorDetect" type="BOOLEAN" value="true"/>
                <d:var name="LinMultiCoreErrorDetect" type="BOOLEAN" 
                       value="true"/>
                <d:var name="LinIndex" type="INTEGER" value="0">
                  <a:a name="IMPORTER_INFO" value="@DEF"/>
                </d:var>
                <d:var name="LinTimeoutDuration" type="INTEGER" value="300">
                  <a:a name="IMPORTER_INFO" value="@DEF"/>
                </d:var>
                <d:var name="LinVersionInfoApi" type="BOOLEAN" value="false"/>
                <d:var name="LinHwMcuTrigSleepEnable" type="BOOLEAN" 
                       value="false"/>
                <d:ref name="LinSysClockRef" type="REFERENCE" 
                       value="ASPath:/Mcu/Mcu/McuModuleConfiguration/McuClockSettingConfig_0/McuClockReferencePointConfig"/>
                <d:var name="LinCsrClksel" type="ENUMERATION" value="ASCLINF"/>
                <d:var name="LinInitApiMode" type="ENUMERATION" 
                       value="LIN_MCAL_SUPERVISOR">
                  <a:a name="IMPORTER_INFO" value="@DEF"/>
                </d:var>
                <d:var name="LinMasterInterruptEnable" type="BOOLEAN" 
                       value="true">
                  <a:a name="IMPORTER_INFO" value="@DEF"/>
                </d:var>
              </d:ctr>
              <d:ctr name="LinGlobalConfig" type="IDENTIFIABLE">
                <a:a name="IMPORTER_INFO" value="ImportEcuConfig"/>
                <d:lst name="LinChannel" type="MAP">
                  <a:a name="IMPORTER_INFO" value="ImportEcuConfig"/>
                  <d:ctr name="LIN_A1" type="IDENTIFIABLE">
                  </d:ctr>
                </d:lst>
              </d:ctr>
            </d:ctr>
          </d:chc>
        </d:lst>
      </d:ctr>
    </d:lst>
  </d:ctr>
</datamodel>
```

Result is:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<datamodel version="7.0"
           xmlns="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/16/root.xsd"
           xmlns:a="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/16/attribute.xsd"
           xmlns:v="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/06/schema.xsd"
           xmlns:d="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/06/data.xsd">

  <d:ctr type="AUTOSAR" factory="autosar"
         xmlns:ad="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/08/admindata.xsd"
         xmlns:cd="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/08/customdata.xsd"
         xmlns:f="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/14/formulaexpr.xsd"
         xmlns:icc="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/08/implconfigclass.xsd"
         xmlns:mt="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/11/multitest.xsd"
         xmlns:variant="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/11/variant.xsd">
    <d:lst type="TOP-LEVEL-PACKAGES">
      <d:ctr name="Lin" type="AR-PACKAGE">
        <d:lst type="ELEMENTS">
          <d:chc name="Lin" type="AR-ELEMENT" value="MODULE-CONFIGURATION">
            <d:ctr type="MODULE-CONFIGURATION">
              <a:a name="DEF" value="ASPath:/TS_T16D27M10I10R0/EcucDefs/Lin"/>
              <d:var name="IMPLEMENTATION_CONFIG_VARIANT" type="ENUMERATION"
                     value="VariantPostBuild"/>
              <d:lst name="LinDemEventParameterRefs" type="MAP"/>
              <d:ctr name="LinGeneral" type="IDENTIFIABLE">
                <d:var name="LinDevErrorDetect" type="BOOLEAN" value="true"/>
                <d:var name="LinMultiCoreErrorDetect" type="BOOLEAN"
                       value="true"/>
                <d:var name="LinIndex" type="INTEGER" value="0"/>
                <d:var name="LinTimeoutDuration" type="INTEGER" value="300"/>
                <d:var name="LinVersionInfoApi" type="BOOLEAN" value="false"/>
                <d:var name="LinHwMcuTrigSleepEnable" type="BOOLEAN"
                       value="false"/>
                <d:ref name="LinSysClockRef" type="REFERENCE"
                       value="ASPath:/Mcu/Mcu/McuModuleConfiguration/McuClockSettingConfig_0/McuClockReferencePointConfig"/>
                <d:var name="LinCsrClksel" type="ENUMERATION" value="ASCLINF"/>
                <d:var name="LinInitApiMode" type="ENUMERATION"
                       value="LIN_MCAL_SUPERVISOR"/>
                <d:var name="LinMasterInterruptEnable" type="BOOLEAN"
                       value="true"/>
              </d:ctr>
              <d:ctr name="LinGlobalConfig" type="IDENTIFIABLE">
                <d:lst name="LinChannel" type="MAP">
                  <d:ctr name="LIN_A1" type="IDENTIFIABLE"/>
                </d:lst>
              </d:ctr>
            </d:ctr>
          </d:chc>
        </d:lst>
      </d:ctr>
    </d:lst>
  </d:ctr>
</datamodel>
```

Comment: Still very curious about your aesthetic need. But like you, I do find the XML standard elegant and poetic representation of data!

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. Python can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with `lxml` but XSLT is not limited to Python but can run in any [standalone processor](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) or other programming languages.

Particularly, with the well-known Identity Transform template you can copy XML as is and then use the empty template to remove needed nodes. Below script removes all `<a:a>` nodes. As commented above and demo below shows, processors may change spacing/indentation (like indented attributes or attribute order) but content should be intact.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/16/root.xsd" 
                xmlns:a="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/16/attribute.xsd" 
                xmlns:v="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/06/schema.xsd" 
                xmlns:d="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/06/data.xsd"
                xmlns:ad="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/08/admindata.xsd" 
                xmlns:cd="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/08/customdata.xsd" 
                xmlns:f="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/14/formulaexpr.xsd" 
                xmlns:icc="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/08/implconfigclass.xsd" 
                xmlns:mt="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/11/multitest.xsd"  
                xmlns:variant="http://www.tresos.de/_projects/DataModel2/11/variant.xsd"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- EMPTY TEMPLATE TO REMOVE NODES -->
  <xsl:template match="a:a"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://www.xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bF2MmY9/)</kbd>

**Python**

```py
import lxml.etree as lx

# PARSE XML AND XSLT
doc = lx.parse("input.xml")
style = lx.parse("style.xsl")

# CONFIGURE AND RUN TRANSFORMER
transformer = lx.XSLT(style)
result = transformer(doc)

# PRINT TO SCREEN
print(result)

# OUTPUT TO FILE
result.write_output("output.xml")
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but this actually modified the internal layout of the attributes, so it did not really answer my question

Comment: Again, as commented above, XML should be fundamentally the same content. Attributes order should not matter in any parser as they do no carry position/index like elements.

Comment: I completely agree that the XML attributes order should not matter, but the problem is that the xml was generated by a tool in a specific order, with a specific layout.  My need was only to remove specific nodes without touching at any other part of the file (hence my initial try with sed!), to be able to track exactly that change in my versioning system.  And since I could not find a solution on the internet, I figured posting here was the best way to share that experience!